# Why should I upgrade my web servers from Windows Server 2008 to R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, web-server, windows-server-2008-r2

Is there any real reason to upgrade my web servers from windows server 2008 to server 2008 R2?  I know I get a new memory manager and IIS 7.5 but what are the actual advantages vs marketing hype.

Comment: "If it ain't broke don't fix it" tends to apply here. If you see nothing wrong with your current setup, I wouldn't mess with it. If you have pain points, it's easier to enumerate the worst ones and see if different software can alleviate those.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it would depend on the role of the application server, but here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008_R2#New_features